# Attempt to speedup python unzip using isal_zlib fails

Tags: python, performance, zip, compression, zlib

I have a long running series of scripts to unpack and analyse a very large dataset. Using pyinstruments I have found out that the ZipFile library is taking up a large amount of time. The files I'm unzipping are actually GLF files - taken from a Tritech Gemini Sonar.

The GLF file itself is actually a zip file with no compression. Inside are a further three files, two of which are important - the cfg and the dat.

The CFG file I can read using just python's open() command, by following the zip file format found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). This is good as it's pretty quick to find the file times I need. I do need to cut off 5 bytes at either end of the data block to make it work. However, the dat file doesn't seem to work in the same way. The dat file contains the images I need to look through and it seems that within this file, each image is compressed using the deflate algorithm.

Now, looking at the zip file local headers, all the files have a bigger compression size than the original size - the act of adding them to a zipfile has actually increased the size. When I look at the header for the dat file it claims to use DEFLATE as the compression type (with 0 as the compression level). This means that running deflate on the dat and cfg files has increased their size (so it appears).

When I read the dat file I get more data than I need, and yet the beginning and ends of this dat file are actually the same as these from an unzipped datfile! Very strange!

I've written a short test to show what is happening. This test fails with:

igzip_lib.IsalError: Error -5 Gzip/zlib wrapper specifies unsupported compress method

```
import os
import struct
from zipfile import ZipFile
from isal import isal_zlib
from pytritech.glf import GLF


def read_raw(glf_path):
    """ Using just normal file reads, find the dat and cfg files."""
   
    with open(glf_path, 'rb') as f:
        glf_file_size = os.path.getsize(glf_path)
        ds = 0

        while ds < glf_file_size:
            file_sig = int(struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0])
            assert file_sig == 0x04034b50

            f.seek(14,1)
            compressed_file_size = int(struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0])
            uncompressed_file_size = int(struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0])
            filename_len = int(struct.unpack("<H", f.read(2))[0])
            extra_field_length = int(struct.unpack("<H", f.read(2))[0])
            filename = str(f.read(filename_len))
            f.seek(extra_field_length, 1)
            f.seek(5, 1) # TODO - this really shouldn't be here but it works! 

            if ".cfg" in filename:
                # we've found the file we need, so read it and return the cfg.
                # We know that this file at any rate is uncompressed.
                # This CFG is correct - it's a bunch of XML therefore the
                # compression is minimal. This doesn't seem to be the case for
                # our dat file however!
                cfg = f.read(uncompressed_file_size).decode("utf-8")
                f.seek(5, 1) # TODO - this really shouldn't be here but it works! 

            elif ".dat" in filename:
                raw_dat = f.read(compressed_file_size)
                return raw_dat
            
            elif ".xml" in filename:
                xml_dat = f.read(compressed_file_size)

            else:
                f.seek(uncompressed_file_size, 1)

            ds += 30 + filename_len + extra_field_length + uncompressed_file_size


def test_raw():
    """ Try and find the difference between a raw read and a ZipFile read."""
    glf_path = "./pytritech_testdata/log_2022-07-22-025519.glf"
    assert os.path.exists(glf_path)

    raw_dat = read_raw(glf_path)
    # Remove the last 5 bytes from raw_dat and the end bit matches!
    raw_dat = raw_dat[:-5]
    dat = None

    zobj = ZipFile(glf_path, "r")
    print("Zobj", zobj, dir(zobj), zobj.compression, zobj.compresslevel)
    for zname in zobj.namelist():
        if "dat" in zname:
            with zobj.open(zname) as f:
                print("fileobj", dir(f), type(f), f._compress_type, f._decompressor, f._orig_file_size, f._orig_compress_size)
                dat = f.read()

    with GLF(glf_path) as glf:
        print("Num images", len(glf.images))
     
    assert(raw_dat[:20] == dat[:20])
    assert(raw_dat[-20:] == dat[-20:])

    decomped = isal_zlib.decompress(raw_dat)

    assert(raw_dat == dat)
```

The line - `decomped = isal_zlib.decompress(raw_dat)` I thought might solve things. It seems to me that a level 0 deflate compression has been applied to that file which has made it larger (as it was quite compressed already due to it being full of compressed images) but for some reason, isal_zlib doesn't want to deflate it.

Is there another speedy way to deflate this binary blob please? It's a big bottle neck (my script takes days to weeks to run)

Comment: Can you post a link to a small example zip file?

Comment: Sadly that might be a problem as the data isn't available for public distribution, at least not at the moment.

Comment: Okay, I managed to find some: https://tritech.wetransfer.com/downloads/63246bc839f06062f4d7becd868da77020230901133019/35a517

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new version of your script at the end of this message.

Let me walk through the changes I've made

### No need to work out the offset for the compressed payload by hand

Working out the offset to the compressed payload in `read_raw` by adding together the lengths of the various parts of the zipfile header data structure (like the filename length) is not necessary. The `zipfile.ZipInfo` class will give you everything you need. The `header_offset` attribute and `FilenameHeader()` method give enough to determine the offset to the compressed payload data. See the rewrite of `read_raw` below.

### isal_zlib.decompress method needs `-zlib.MAX_WBITS` option

You need to include the parameter `wbits=-zlib.MAX_WBITS` when uncompressing the deflate content used in zip files.

```
import os
import struct
from zipfile import ZipFile
from isal import isal_zlib
import zlib

def read_raw(glf_path):
    zobj = ZipFile(glf_path, "r")

    offset = 0
    size = 0

    # get the offset to the compressed payload data
    for zinfo in zobj.infolist():
        if "dat" in zinfo.filename:
            print(f'{zinfo.filename}: offset {zinfo.header_offset} payload { zinfo.header_offset+ len(zinfo.FileHeader())} ')
            offset = zinfo.header_offset + len(zinfo.FileHeader())
            size = zinfo.compress_size
            break

    # now read & return the compressed payload
    with open(glf_path, mode="rb") as fh:
        fh.seek(offset)
        return fh.read(size)


def test_raw(glf_path):
    """ Try and find the difference between a raw read and a ZipFile read."""
    assert os.path.exists(glf_path)

    raw_dat = read_raw(glf_path)

    dat = None

    zobj = ZipFile(glf_path, "r")

    for zname in zobj.namelist():
        if "dat" in zname:
            with zobj.open(zname) as f:
                print(f"{zname}")
                dat = f.read()
                break

    print(f'Decompressed to {len(dat)} bytes')

    # uncompress with isal
    isal_decomped = isal_zlib.decompress(raw_dat, wbits=-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    print(f'Decompressed to {len(isal_decomped)} bytes')

    # uncompress with zlib
    zlib_decomped = zlib.decompress(raw_dat, wbits=-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    print(f'Decompressed to {len(zlib_decomped)} bytes')

    # check that zlib & isal uncompress to the same data
    assert(isal_decomped == zlib_decomped)

    # and matched what zipfile got
    assert(zlib_decomped == dat)

test_raw('log_2021-11-11-140826.glf')
```

When I run that I using the file `log_2021-11-11-140826.glf` that was included in the link you supplied, I get this

```
$ python3 try.py 
data_2021-11-11-140826.dat: offset 15282 payload 15338 
data_2021-11-11-140826.dat
Decompressed to 314243167 bytes
Decompressed to 314243167 bytes
Decompressed to 314243167 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help there! :) My concern, perhaps not properly stated by me, is that I was avoiding any use of the ZipFile library as I found it was causing a lot of slowdown. I found that I could read the cfg file just using the basic file reading functions and was hoping I could do the same for the dat. Perhaps it’s not possible?

Comment: However I think that maybe just replacing all the decompression parts with Isal might be enough.

Comment: Putting aside the cost of whatever processing you are doing with the uncompressed data, it is likely that the place where your code is spending its time is in IO and/or  uncompression. One thing to consider is whether you should do streaming uncompression (whether it would make any difference depends on the nature of your workflow). Rather than uncompress the while file in one big-bang and have it stored in-memory, or back to disk (which means more disk IO), you  have a read/uncompress loop that gives you the uncompressed data a bit at a time. As I say, it ultimately depends on your workflow.

Comment: Thanks - that's definitely a factor for sure. The .dat file itself allows for this as the headers for each image are not compressed but the image data itself is. I'll think on and see if there's more I can do to speed things up.